# Adding a Second Page To an App

Tags: android, multipage

I have an app that has too much information in one spot so I wanted to add in a next button
that would lead to a new page for more information. Is there an easy way to do this? (I am currently a novice user).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new activity page2 and have a button listener on page1 that leads to page2. Or you can use ScrollView or SlidingDrawer too.

Comment: awesome thanks.. I knew what i wanted to do i just wasnt sure what it would be called